# Problems with C++ video example: opencv_ffmpeg.dll "corrupt"

Tags: affdex-sdk

I was trying to run the video-demo sample application in the Affdex SDK, but ran into a linker error. In the in instruction page (http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/windows/) there is a point where it states:
"A dynamic library, opencv_ffmpeg.dll is required by VideoDetector". However, I could not find this .dll as part of either the SDK package or the github example code.

I downloaded the openCV version 3.1 which was mentioned as required dependency, but it did not have opencv_ffmpeg.dll either. It did have two files that seemed relevant : opencv_ffmpeg310.dll and opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll. However, when I try to link the project with either of these files, I get the error:

Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file

So, I was just wondering what I'm doing wrong, and where could I find the correct opencv_ffmpeg.dll.

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

- A dynamic library, **opencv_ffmpeg.dll** is required by VideoDetector [[c++]](http://developer.affectiva.com/pages/platforms/v3/cpp/classdocs/affdex-native/classaffdex_1_1_video_detector.html) in runtime for the video decoding.
- You can download the Affdex SDK 3.0 for Windows from the [downloads page](http://developer.affectiva.com/downloads/current/). Based on the architecture for which you downloaded the SDK for you can locate either opencv_ffmpeg248_64.dll at `C:\Program Files\Affectiva\Affdex SDK\bin`or opencv_ffmpeg248.dll at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Affectiva\Affdex SDK\bin`.